# How to resolve " mysqldump: Error 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query when dumping table "

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a database with a size of 8GB, Whenever I tried to take a backup for the database it through an Error 2013 Lost connection during query when dumping the database. I have increased the time_outs to 28600 and I got the same problem.

Max_allowed_packet=16MB, 
MySQL Version: 5.6, 
Engine: Innodb

Anyone help me with it

Comment: Check the solutions here, it may be helpful. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/97846/mysqldump-error-2013